# External usb not support

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean

I have Karbonn a18+ and its kernal does not support otg as well as seed charge.the is kernel version is 3.4.5 someone help me.I want otg support .

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the hardware supports OTG functionality.

If hardware supports, check for any custom ROM (such as [CyanogenMod](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Devices)) is released for your device.

Follow their procedure to flash the custom ROM.